# Spring core. Default @Bean destroy method

Tags: java, spring, release

I have my own bean:

```
@Bean
public MyBean myBean(){...
```

following spring documentation to release its own resources I should specify `destroyMethod`. I've not found any default destroy methods called by spring in case if `destroyMethod` is not specified directly.

I used

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public MyBean myBean(){...
```

but think about possibility to do not specify destroy method directly if it has value by default.

---

Does spring try something by default like `destroy`, `close`, `release`?
If spring tries some methods by default to release resources - which ones?

Comment: I think no. It would be very unclear, you need an annotation like `@PreDestroy` or `@Bean(destroyMethod = "...")`, or implement `DisposableBean`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As documented in [`Bean.destroyMethod`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#destroyMethod--):

> As a convenience to the user, the container will attempt to infer a
>   destroy method against an object returned from the `@Bean` method. For
>   example, given an `@Bean` method returning an Apache Commons DBCP
>   `BasicDataSource`, the container will notice the `close()` method
>   available on that object and automatically register it as the
>   `destroyMethod`. This 'destroy method inference' is currently limited
>   to detecting only public, no-arg methods named 'close' or 'shutdown'.

In other words, if you don't specify `destroyMethod`, but the bean has a public `close()` or `shutdown()` method, it will be automatically used as the destroy-method.

To disable this inference, use `@Bean(destroyMethod = "")`.

Comment: Besides the public close() method, there is also @PreDestroy annotation and DisposableBean interface. Is there any recommended or generally preferred way to go?

Comment: @dpelisek `@Bean` with a `destroyMethod` will work for any class used as a bean, even if you can't modify the class. Using `@PreDestroy` means you need to have access to the source of that class to be able to add that annotation to the right method, similar for `DisposableBean`: you need to be able to implement that interface. So, if it is your own code, by all means use `@PreDestroy` or `DisposableBean` (personally I would prefer the annotation over the interface), but for third-party classes you usually don't have the choice.

Answer (score 21):

You can implement a method which will be executed before destroying and annotate it with `@PreDestroy`

```
@PreDestroy
public void methodName() {
    //Your code..
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean interface specifies a single method −

```
void destroy() throws Exception;
```

Simply implement it −

```
public class ExampleBean implements DisposableBean {
   public void destroy() {
      // do some destruction work
   }
}
```

for XML-based configuration

```
<bean id = "exampleBean" class = "examples.ExampleBean" destroy-method = "destroy"/>
```

and in the bean

```
public class ExampleBean {
   public void destroy() {
      // do some destruction work
   }
}
```

or annotate with @PreDestroy

Answer (score 4):

You can extend [`DisposableBeanAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.0/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DisposableBeanAdapter.html) class. One of the methods it provides is the `destroy` method being called by Spring. This way you don't have to provide any implementation while it is required when you're using `DisposableBean` interface.