# Make a member of a bean available for autowiring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

```
@Component
class MultiProvider {
    public Foo getFoo();
    public Bar getBar();
}

@Component
class FooConsumer {
    FooConsumer(Foo f);
}
```

Can I have `MultiProvider.getFoo()` autowired into the `FooConsumer` constructor..

- without making `Foo` a bean itself (for example, because Spring should not destroy it, since that is `MultiProvider`s responsibility)
- and without introducing a dependency from `FooConsumer` to `MultiProvider` (or any other class)?

Comment: why are you using @Bean on the class ? @ Bean is a method level annotation https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband oops, I meant Component

Comment: what do you mean by this `without making Foo a bean itself` Autowire will happen only between beans, you can autowire only bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this simply by annotating `getFoo()` method in `MultiProvider` by `@Bean`

```
@Component
class MultiProvider {
    @Bean(destroyMethodName="cleanup")      // HERE IS THE TRICK
    public Foo getFoo();
    public Bar getBar();
}

@Component
class FooConsumer {
    FooConsumer(Foo f);
}
```

if the problem comes from the point that spring can not properly destroy it you can include the logic inside `cleanup` method declared while annotating by `@Bean`

```
public class Foo {
    public void cleanup() {
        // destruction logic
    }
}
```

---

> Note that @component and @configurable are more or less the same with
>   some subtle differences but in your case you can use @component if you don't
>   want to change it. [More Info](http://dimafeng.com/2015/08/29/spring-configuration_vs_component/)

Comment: I've reworded my question a bit. I didn't want Spring to destroy Foo because that is MultiProviders responsibility. However, since destroy should be idempotent anyway (in my current opinion at least :P ) I was just being pedantic, and this is how I've solved it indeed (but without the custom `destroyMethodName`)

Answer (score 0):

Spring can only autowire declared beans, a possible workaround can be something like the following:

```
@Component
class FooConsumer {
    private final Foo foo;

    FooConsumer(MultiProvider multiProvider) {
        // MultiProvider will be autowired by spring - constructor injection
        this.foo = multiProvider.getFoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course, but my purpose is to not have a dependency from FooConsumer on MultiProvider. I should clarify that

Comment: That is not possible as far as I know, you can only autowire beans

Comment: I don't know if its relevant, but you can specify `Foo` as a bean and add a `close()` method with your `destroy` logic so spring will destroy it correctly. Then you can maybe define it as a bean and autowire it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44757112/4473822

Answer (score 0):

You can include them in your `Configuration`.

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public MultiProvider getMP() {
        return new MultiProvider() ;
   }
   @Bean
   public Foo getFoo() {
        return getMP(). getFoo();
   } 
}
```

Not sure if that violates your 'not a Bean itself' rule.

Comment: I've reworded the question to expand on the nonbeanrule